# FTP Credentials requested when trying to activate WordPress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

Running an instance of Bitnami Wordpress on AWS Lightsail. Getting the following screen when trying to activate a Wordpress theme (JobCareer): 
[image]

**UPDATE #1** Turned on debug and saw the error information in the above screenshot.

Other themes and plugins I have tested all installed and activate without issue, so it's probably something specific to this theme.

I have made sure that `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` is set inside wp-config.php file.

The wp-content folder and sub-folders/files are all chown to `bitnami` user and have the appropriate permissions (folder:755 & files:644).

At a loss as to what else to try. Thanks for any help you can provide! :)

Comment: Moved the `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` line back to it's original spot.

Comment: Posting what finally worked for me for others benefit. It WAS a permissions issue. For my Bitnami Wordpress installation on AWS Lightsail, the user to set as the owner of the wp-contents was `daemon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely a files & directories permission issue. Move the `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` line back to where it was (that change is causing a different error).

The 'www-data' user is the default user for Apache (and other HTTP servers?), in case you didn't know.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that, though kept seeing that come up in me searches for a solution. Do you know what would be the correct files/dirs permissions command to run? I've got wordpress folder setup as `/home/bitnami/apps/wordpress`.

Comment: Well, the HTTP server needs to have read and write permissions on the directories and the files within them. I'm not familiar with AWS Lightsail so you may need to put in a trouble ticket to get that sorted out.

Comment: A possible workaround: install another WP instance, see what the reported owner and group names are.

In the code snippet provided by user1102392, the "username:www-data" pair is the owner and group, so according to standard unix file perms the owner (username) has full read & write perms (the 1st digit) while the group (www-data, the 2nd digit) only has read perms. That won't work obviously, the HTTP server needs write as well as read perms. The correct owner:group pairing varies by host & configuration.